# Де/сериализация сложного вложенного json в c#

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Есть json подобного вида:
`{ [object, “AND”, [object, “OR”, object]], “OR”, object }`
*“AND”, “OR”* etc. - это обычные string’и, которые воспринимаются сервером аналогично операторам в sql запросе, например.
Вопрос в том как элегантнее сериализовать и десериализовать такой объект? И возможно ли это? Может можно написать кастомный сериализатор и если да, то в каком виде передавать ему этот объект для парсинга? Есть ли варианты, кроме обычного string’a? Хотелось бы видеть что-то типа `(Object1.And(Object2.Or(Object3))).Or(Object4)`. Есть ли какие-то возможности?

Конкретный пример json:

```
"jsonObject":[ 
  [ { "name":"Name1", "value":"1" }, "AND", { "name":"Name2", "value":"2" } ], 
  "OR", 
  [ { "name":"Name3", "value":"3" }, "AND", { "name":"Name4", "value":"4" } ]
}
```

Comment: Пример json?  Что сами уже пытались?

Comment: Конкретный пример json приведите в задании. То, что у вас написано -- это не json, эта строка не пройдёт валидацию. Вы хотите изобрести свой собственный язык?

Comment: Пример есть в вопросе. Если более развернуто, то:
"jsonObject":[
      [
         {
           "name":"Name1",
           "value":"1"
         },
         "AND",
         {
           "name":"Name2",
           "value":"2"
         }
      ],
      "OR",
     [  
        {
           "name":"Name3",
           "value":"3"
        },
        "AND",
        {
           "name":"Name4",
           "value":"4"
        }
     ]
}
Пока не могу придумать в каком виде это сделать. Вообще мне реализация не нужна, только идея, если есть какие-то варианты, реализовать-то я смогу

Comment: Странное решение - использовать массивы с разными объектами. Это вы сами такой json генерируете? Парсить его скорее всего придется своим конвертером, не думаю, что есть что то встроенное для такого.

Comment: Сама я бы даже не придумала такое, это API сервер такой объект принимает, а я клиент пишу. Вот и ищу как с ним подружиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) позволяет регистрировать свои собственные конвертеры для определенного класса. Посмотреть примеры можно здесь: [How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to).

Я не претендую на то что правильно понял вашу задачу, но пример решения возможно не помешает.

Объекты:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
public abstract class MyObjectBase {
    public static MyObject Create(string name, string value) => new MyObject() { Name = name, Value = value };
    public abstract MyObjectGroup And(string name, string value);
    public abstract MyObjectGroup Or(string name, string value);
}
public class MyObject : MyObjectBase {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override MyObjectGroup And(string name, string value) {
        MyObjectGroup grp = new MyObjectGroup();
        grp.GroupType = MyObjectGroupType.And;
        grp.Items.Add(this);
        grp.Items.Add(Create(name, value));
        return grp;
    }
    public override MyObjectGroup Or(string name, string value) {
        MyObjectGroup grp = new MyObjectGroup();
        grp.GroupType = MyObjectGroupType.And;
        grp.Items.Add(this);
        grp.Items.Add(Create(name, value));
        return grp;
    }
}
public class MyObjectGroup : MyObjectBase {
    public MyObjectGroupType GroupType { get; set; }
    public IList<MyObjectBase> Items { get; } = new List<MyObjectBase>();
    public override MyObjectGroup And(string name, string value) {
        if(GroupType == MyObjectGroupType.And) {
            Items.Add(Create(name, value));
            return this;
        }
        MyObjectGroup grp = new MyObjectGroup();
        grp.GroupType = MyObjectGroupType.And;
        grp.Items.Add(this);
        grp.Items.Add(Create(name, value));
        return grp;
    }
    public override MyObjectGroup Or(string name, string value) {
        if(GroupType == MyObjectGroupType.Or) {
            Items.Add(Create(name, value));
            return this;
        }
        MyObjectGroup grp = new MyObjectGroup();
        grp.GroupType = MyObjectGroupType.Or;
        grp.Items.Add(this);
        grp.Items.Add(Create(name, value));
        return grp;
    }
}
public enum MyObjectGroupType { And, Or }
```

Конвертер:

```cs
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyObjectBase> {
    public override MyObjectBase Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        switch(reader.TokenType) {
            case JsonTokenType.StartArray:
                return ReadGroup(ref reader);
            case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(ref reader);
            default:
                throw new JsonException($"Unexpected token type '{reader.TokenType}'. 'StartArra' or 'StartObject' is expected.");
        }
    }
    static MyObject ReadObject(ref Utf8JsonReader reader) {
        if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException($"Unexpected token: '{reader.TokenType}'. 'StartObject' is expected.");
        string name = string.Empty;
        string value = string.Empty;
        while(reader.Read()) {
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                return MyObjectBase.Create(name, value);
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName) {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch(propertyName) {
                    case nameof(MyObject.Name):
                        name = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case nameof(MyObject.Value):
                        value = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new JsonException($"Unknown property: '{propertyName}'.");
                }
            }
        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }
    static MyObjectGroup ReadGroup(ref Utf8JsonReader reader) {
        if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException($"Unexpected token '{reader.TokenType}'. 'StartArray' is expected.");
        MyObjectGroup result = new MyObjectGroup();
        while(reader.Read()) {
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                return result;
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                result.Items.Add(ReadGroup(ref reader));
            else if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                result.Items.Add(ReadObject(ref reader));
            else if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String) {
                string value = reader.GetString();
                MyObjectGroupType groupType;
                if(Enum.TryParse<MyObjectGroupType>(value, out groupType))
                    result.GroupType = groupType;
                else
                    throw new JsonException($"Unexpected keyword '{value}'. 'AND' or 'OR' is expected.");
            }
        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyObjectBase value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        if(value is MyObject obj)
            WriteObject(writer, obj);
        else if(value is MyObjectGroup grp)
            WriteGroup(writer, grp, options);
        else
            throw new JsonException();
    }
    static void WriteObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyObject value) {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(MyObject.Name));
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Name);
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(MyObject.Value));
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    static void WriteGroup(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyObjectGroup value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < value.Items.Count; i ++) {
            MyObjectBase item = value.Items[i];
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, typeof(MyObjectBase), options);
            if(i < value.Items.Count - 1)
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.GroupType.ToString());
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```cs
var obj = MyObjectBase.Create("Name1", "1")
    .And("Name2", "2")
    .Or("Name3", "3")
    .Or("Name4", "4");

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyObjectBase>(obj);

var obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObjectBase>(json);
```

Comment: Да, это оно, спасибо вам большое!